# Merge, join or append the data of two Rxjs Obresvable

Tags: angular, merge, pagination, ionic3, observable

For pagination purpose I am using the following code in Ionic 3 using Angular and Firestore.

First time request:

```
collObs: Observable<any>;
more: Observable<any>;

this.collObs = this.afs.collection('data').limit(10).snapshotChanges().map(a=>{
        return a.map(x=> {
          return {
            value: x.payload.doc.data(),
          };
        });
      });
```

Then I am gerring the last document snapshot in `lastDocSnap` variable

Load More on page end:

```
this.more = this.afs.collection('data').startAfter(lastDocSnap).limit(10).snapshotChanges().map(a=>{
        return a.map(x=> {
          return {
            value: x.payload.doc.data(),
          };
        });
      });
```

How how do I append the result of `more` with `collObs`. I have tried `Observable.merge(this.collObs, this.more)` but it is not working and overlaping the previous result.

Comment: Also have a look at [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

Answer (score 0):

If they are both arrays you can actually use the spread operator like so:

`this.collObs = [...this.collObs, ...this.more]`

If they are both objects you can try obj.spread

`this.collObs = {...this.collObs, ...this.more}`

Comment: The Observable is not an Array type. It's an object. So this solution will not work for me.

Comment: The Async pipe is not able to handle it and giving this error - `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`. It is creating an object with 2, not merging it to one.